# InfluxDB missing tag value (putInfluxDB nifi processor)

Tags: python, json, apache-kafka, apache-nifi, influxdb

i'm new in InfluxDB, the problem consists in that i have to insert python dicts in InfluxDB via Nifi and i have tried different ways and i allways got the same error telling that tag is missing:

[image]

```
org.influxdb.InfluxDBException: {
    "error": "unable to parse '[
        {
          "measurement": "sensor",
          "time": 1559560006,
          "tags": [
            "sensor",
            "id",
            "date",
            "info",
            "aleatory_number",
            "aleatory_number_square_root"
          ],
          "fields": {
            "id": 8,
            "date": 1559559961002,
            "info": "info sensor8",
            "aleatory_number": 1778687859,
            "aleatory_number_square_root": 42174.492
          }
        }
      ]': missing tag value"
}
```

Another example:

```
{
  "error":"unable to parse 
  '[{
    "measurement":"sensor",
    "time":1559630455,
    "tags":{"test_tag":"test"},
    "fields":{}
    }]'
    : missing tag value"
}
```

Another:

```
org.influxdb.InfluxDBException: 
{
  "error":"unable to parse 
  '[{
    "measurement":"sensor",
    "time":1559631341,
    "tags":{},
    "fields":{}
    }]'
    : missing tag value"}
```

My last try follows this avro schema:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "preprocessed_value",
  "fields": [
    { "name": "measurement", "type": "string"  },
    { "name": "time", "type": "long"  },
    { "name": "tags", "type": { "type":"map", "values" : "string"}  },
    { 
      "name" : "fields" , 
      "type" : {
        "name" : "PythonDict",
        "type" : "record",
        "fields": [
          { "name": "id",                           "type": "int" },
          { "name": "date",                         "type": "long"  },
          { "name": "info",                         "type": "string"  },
          { "name": "aleatory_number",              "type": "long"  },
          { "name": "aleatory_number_square_root",  "type": "float" }
        ]
      } 
    }
  ]
}
```

And i got the same error using tags and fields simultaneously:

```
org.influxdb.InfluxDBException: {"error":"unable to parse 
  '[{
    "measurement":"sensor",
    "time":1559720142,
    "tags":{"test_tag":"test"},
    "fields":{
      "id":3,
      "date":1559718332366,
      "info":"info sensor3",
      "aleatory_number":141969819,
      "aleatory_number_square_root":11915.108
      }
  }]': missing tag value"}
```

Comment: It looks like the `sensor` tag doesn't have a value specified in the `fields` element. Can you check the flowfile contents in NiFi (pause the `PutInfluxDB` processor and _List Queue_ on the incoming connection to see individual flowfile values) to see if a sensor value is present?

Comment: First of all thanks, but i got the same error, deleting tag "sensor" or even with an empty array as "tags"

Answer (score 3):

If the record(point as per InfluxDB terminology) that you are trying to insert into measurement 'sensor' do not have value or has null value for any tags, you will get this error.

I am not sure, why you have almost similar tags and fields for your measurement. For a point, tag columns are mandatory data and field columns are optional.

Execute following command on influx cli:

```
show tag keys from sensor;
```

This will list all tagged columns from your measurement. Make sure you are passing all those while trying to insert new point.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have tried this and the error continues, do you see some error?:

    {
      "error":"unable to parse 
      '[{
        "measurement":"sensor",
        "time":1559630455,
        "tags":{"test_tag":"test"},
        "fields":{}
        }]'
        : missing tag value"
    }

Comment: @ÁngelIgualada I have edited the answer, please try as suggest

Comment: Thanks, i have tried, but how i got the error in every insert, the measurement is not created yet, so there is no tag show

Comment: @ÁngelIgualada Can you try to insert some data directly using CLI using influxql. It will help us to isolate the issue

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, none of your tags have values. In your second example, you are writing a point that has no fields; which is not allowed either.

Your point should look like:

```
{
    "measurement":"sensor",
    "time":1559630455,
    "tags":{"test_tag":"test"},
    "fields":{"some_field": 1}
}
```